# Correct model to use for flexible survey in MVC 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm looking to create an MVC application to edit the results of various customer surveys. but I’m struggling to get the approach/ model right in my head.

I have survey results that are stored across different database tables (one table for each version of the survey) with each version having a slightly different set of columns. I've created a combined (Sql)view which just shows the table columns that i want to edit, as the source tables contain a lot of irrelevant columns.

> CREATE VIEW [vw_CombinedSurveyResults] AS
>
> SELECT     'V10_v2' as anTable, UniqueRecordID, ddDate, iIncidNo, bA, bB, bC, null as 'bD 
>   FROM        V10_v2
>
> UNION 
>   SELECT     '10_v1' as anTable, UniqueRecordID, ddDate, iIncidNo, bA, bB, null as bC, bD 
>   FROM V10_v1
>
> UNION 
>   SELECT    'V9_v6' as anTable,  UniqueRecordID, ddDate, iIncidNo, bA, null as bB, null as bC, bD 
>   FROM         V9_v6

My first idea was to search the combined (sql)view (filtering by date and the incident number) to and then display the results in a table, so far so good.

The part where I’m having a brain freeze is deciding on how best to update a selected individual survey records is a neat and tidy way, and in a way that will require minimal effort when the future versions of the survey are created.

So far I’ve got created a sql view for each of the  source tables (cut down to just have the columns I’m interested in) and using these views to create some Linq To Sql classes for each of the source cut-down views. (These are the ‘Models’)

I’ve used one of these autogenerated classes as the model a to create strongly typed view for editing the survey values (of just one version, v10_v2) .

I’ve got a controller for updating a cut-down view (V10_v2)  and that all works  fine … but that is just for one survey version which proves a concept but it’s very clunky.

To  continue down this path will mean  I’ll need to create multiple (MVC) views and controllers, one for each survey table, but there must be a slicker/easier way of organising  the models or views or both?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What is your question... (Note: change the title of this question - Too localized right now?)

Comment: @Nate - thanks for the edit, my brain freeze extended to the question title as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break down the tables differently...

```
Surveys
-------
Id
Name
...

Fields
------
Id
SurveyId
Name
DataType

Answers
-------
Id
SurveyId
UserId
...

IntegerValues
-------------
Id
FieldId
AnswerId
Value (INTEGER)

StringValues
------------
Id
FieldId
AnswerId
Value (VARCHAR)
```

In this way, everything is totally flexible, you end up with a table for each data type and thus can access it in a strongly-typed way. You'd need a `switch`/`select case` statement to determine which values table to query based on the field definition

**Re: Viewmodels**

There are a number of options here...

Firstly, you could create multiple models which inherit from a common field model, one per data type. Then, your questionnaire viewmodel would look something like...

```
Public Class QViewModel
    Public Property QuestionnaireId As Integer
    Public Property Fields As List(Of QField)
    ...
End Class


Public Class QField
    Public Property FieldName As String
End Class

Public Class QFieldInteger
    Inherits QField
    Public Property Value as Integer
End Class

Public Class QFieldString
    Inherits QField
    Public Property Value as String
End Class
```

This would allow you to add any number of `QFieldstring`, `QFieldInteger`, etc... to the model when you create it to represent your questionnaire. You could also add custom editors if you needed them for other field types (eg a multiple choice answer which maps to an integer, much like an enum)

Alternatively, you *could* build the whole thing using reflection dynamically either via [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) (Fast, complex) or the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) (Slower at run-time, simple to use). This would mean you could create an abstract class for each survey with properties of the appropriate type.

The latter approach (Reflection.Emit/CodeDOM) is more complex to set up but would allow for greater flexibility if you want to tweak things further down the line (eg you could add custom validation attributes to your class properties directly when defining the class). You'd have to worry about things like caching instantiated classes, making sure that your generated classes couldn't be subverted (eg by someone storing .Net code in a field name in the database), making your actions and methods handle the dynamically generated classes and a whole slew of other things.

I'd recommend you start with the Multiple models approach and switch if you can't get the control you need.

Comment: This is clearly the best approach.  Using metadata to describe the surveys.  Alternatively if you cannot change you existing "one table for each version" methodology you could still describe those tables with metadata and then build dynamic SQL strings (yuck!)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've seen a simalar approach before where the values were all saved in the same table (eg a a column for stringvalues, intvalues, decimal values etc) but I like the idea of having one table per data type.

Comment: @user1635901 You're welcome - I personally prefer table-per-type as it means you don't have blank cells all over the shop for no reason. It feels more efficient to me (at least once you've completed the initial setup of the tables). If this is the answer you decide to go with, please use the tick on the left hand side to accept it. If you need more information, please ask. If you want to wait for other answers, not a problem. Anyway, welcome to SO and we'll hopefully see you around in future.

Comment: @Basic - Thanks for your quick responses, i've a follow up question... how would the views (or view models) look that would enable an end user to edit multiple values at once (eg one section of the survey)?

Comment: @Basic - once again a great answer, thanks for all your help.

Comment: @user1635901 You're very welcome. As I said, hope to see you around in future